# How to limit user's comments/requests per hour in php

Tags: php, time, authorization

I have a site that has few request options (for example add photo, add comment). I want to limit of requests made by use per certain time, for example so he can't post more than 5 comments within hour, he can't add more than 5 photos per hour etc.

My idea was to make/update session variable every time form action is sent, so it sums up to 5 (and if session var == 5 it would deny action on every form). My idea seems good in my mind, but i just can't find the way to reset certain session variable 1 hour from it's initation). Looking forward for any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it from SQL using simple SQL commands you can get the number of items done in the past hour and thus no need to use session variables (which will die if a user reset it's session)

**Check the number of "posts" for a specific element in the current hour**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    my_elements_table 
WHERE 
    HOUR(createdon) = HOUR(NOW()) 
    AND DATE(createdon) = CURDATE()
    AND createdby = the_user_you_are_checking
```

**Check the number of "posts" for a specific element in the past hour**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    my_elements_table 
WHERE 
    DATE_ADD(createdon, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > NOW() 
    AND createdby = the_user_you_are_checking
```

Obviously, adapt the SQL based on your database fields and tables but you should have a good starting point with that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you store data about the comments and the photos in a database, at least you have to do it about the comments, but I guess you do it for the photos as well. In that case I would save a timestamp for when the comment/photo was created and an ID of the user who created it, along with the rest of the information.

When a user then tries to add another photo or comment, you count the number of comments and photos in the db that were created by that particular user within the last 60 minutes. If it exceeds five, you discard the request, otherwise you add the information.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you got users, you store them in a database, don't you ? Then why not just store the last time they commented something in the database and use that to check if they can comment ?

Comment: But if you only store the last time they did something, how would you know if they did something five times within the last hour?

Answer (score 0):

Make 5 variables in the session containing the time of the actions and every time a user is trying to post check to see first if all 5 have something recorded and if  all of them have data check the time recorded.If all times are within one hour from the current time then deny access.

Comment: A little bit like i said in the post of Krister Andersson, you can't use anything based on cookies because of automated attacks. They won't care about your session mechanism, they can just log back in, post, ditch your session cookie and start over. Same thing for user, if he wants to store many pictures and finds out that he can just log off and log back in, you failed your mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to query your database to return comments posted within your specified time frame and if the result count is higher than allowed, don't allow new comment.

Something like: "SELECT created_on FROM tblComments WHERE user_id=**x**"

With this I am making an assumption that you are storing comments in a database and that you have a field containing the post time.